# how to get nuget unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, nuget

I referred to this one
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2017#taking-advantage-of-net-compatibility

i attempted to get nuget npgsql and microsoft office
but this error is occured.

```
Assembly 'Assets/Plugin/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'office'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Microsoft.Vbe.Interop'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
```

it was same to  happen exactly like npgsql

how to get nuget in unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this asset: https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity

Comment: Assembly 'Assets/Packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.15.0.4795.1000/lib/net20/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'office'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Microsoft.Vbe.Interop'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.                       error is occured  hahahahahahaha